# ckeditor + setData = extra paragraphs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use a fresh version of CKEditor. The problem I face is extra paraghraphs or `<p>` tags around data when I do `setData`. I do it like this:

```
editor.setData(editor.getData()+' some text ');
```

Instead of adding just:

```
 some text
```

it adds:

```
<p> some text </p>
```

I wonder, if there is some config that I can play around to remove this unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the source? My guess is that the original data is itself wrapped in a paragraph. You're adding some text after the paragraph closes, so the browser interprets it as a new paragraph.

Comment: That is a good guess. Actually, I have just found necessary configs to do the trick: enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P, autoParagraph: false. Now, it works as I expect it to see.

Comment: I would be a little wary of changing those flags (I'm not necessary saying it's the wrong thing to do). They dramatically affect the behavior of CKEditor in a way which might be unexpected, just for one API call.

Comment: By the way, guys, does anybody know the config for a 'full' toolbar? In previous versions there was toolbar: 'Full' config, but I see, that now it has no effect